# How should I build the relationships between my tables?

Tags: php, mysql, invoice, relational, integrity

I am building an Invoicing Component into my Web Application.
In My Schema we have levels at which certain customers may want to invoice.

```
Projects -> Sites -> Jobs -> Phases -> Teams
```

Each of these are tables in the database and have a relationship to their parent.

I plan on building an **Items** table that will hold the generic information on how we will invoice for the work being done at each of those levels, i.e Name, Default Price, Unit of Measure, etc.

Then the user will create an **Invoicing Model** that they can relate a list of **Items** to, so that these can be reusable.

This is where my questions comes into play. When it is time to Invoice I need to relate an **Invoicing Model** to one of the above mentioned levels. I do not want to create a linking table for each of these levels to the Invoicing Model. I'd like to somehow keep relational integrity between tables. But also, if there is something else that in the future I can bill against I don't want to have to make a huge database change and/or code change to take this new "Billable Level" into account.

Is there a way for me to keep relational integrity without creating a new table to link Invoicing Models to the level?

Comment: Referential integrity is lost with polymorphic relationships, but it sounds like it may be a good option for you.

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand "I need to relate an Invoicing Model to one of the above mentioned levels".  If an invoice is, as you even say, a list of items, isn't _that_ the relationship?  You have an Invoices table, and Items table, and an Invoice_Item (invoiceId, itemId) table.  You just have the _one_ "linking" table, not one per item type.

Comment: @PatrickQ An Invoicing Model is basically how someone invoices, and I forgot to mention that you can invoice the same level twice for the same Invoicing Model. In the end, there will be an invoices and invoice_items table. But that comes after you go to invoice a "level".

Comment: You can have multiple nullable FK to different level tables in single table, so integrity will be there

Comment: @IlyaBursov I've thought about this solution too. But it has bit me in the butt previously, trying to join on that same table multiple times to get information for every level underneath the level in question.

Comment: @Devon Pros and cons on polymorphic relationships?

Comment: @BillyStalnaker, The pro would be the ability to "attach" new entity types without having to expand your tables.  The con would be the loss of some referential integrity depending on the implementation.  This might be a good read:  https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/modeling-polymorphic-associations-in-a-relational-database

Comment: @Devon great read. It looks like he recommends the Exclusive Belongs To approach. Which is what ilyaBursov  mentioned. Thank you so much!

Comment: @BillyStalnaker yes, it is the same for all solutions, with single polymorphic table you have to read it multiple times, with separate tables you will read all of them too (they are in total equal to single table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polymorphic relationships can be implemented which solve the problem of attaching "n" number of different entity types.

The downside to polymorphic relationships is, as far as I know, it's impossible to implement without some loss of referential integrity.

A good read on this would be https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/modeling-polymorphic-associations-in-a-relational-database.  One of the popular, and simplest, implementations would be the Polymorphic Joins, quoted from the article below:

> **Polymorphic Joins**
>
> A simple approach to connect an acl to a resource is to use two
>   columns on the acl table: resource_type and resource_id. This approach
>   was popularized by Ruby on Rails. The acl table could be defined as
>   follows:

```
create table acl(
  id serial primary key,
  resource_type varchar not null,
  resource_id integer not null,
  -- other fields omitted
  unique(resource_id, resource_type)
);
```

> The query for retrieving an acl for document id:42 would be like the
>   following:

```
select *
from acl
where resource_type='document'
  and resource_id=42;
```

> A serious problem with this approach is the database is very limited
>   in the data integrity it can enforce due to the lack of foreign key
>   constraints. It can ensure a resource has no more that one acl, but
>   that is all. A resource can be missing an acl and an acl can point to
>   a missing resource.

---

The Exclusive Belongs To method is a good method of increasing referential integrity but would require a new column for each possible entity type.  Quoted from the article:

> **Exclusive Belongs To (AKA Exclusive Arc)** In this model, the acl has foreign keys to all tables to which it can belong.

```
create table acl(
  id serial primary key,
  document_id integer references document,
  image_id integer references image,
  file_id integer references file,
  report_id integer references report,
  -- other fields omitted
  check(
    (
      (document_id is not null)::integer +
      (image_id is not null)::integer +
      (file_id is not null)::integer +
      (report_id is not null)::integer 
    ) = 1
  )
);

create unique index on acl (document_id) where document_id is not null;
create unique index on acl (image_id) where image_id is not null;
create unique index on acl (file_id) where file_id is not null;
create unique index on acl (report_id) where report_id is not null;
```

> Take note of the check constraint. This ensures that an acl belongs to
>   exactly one resource of any type. With this design an acl cannot be
>   orphaned, but there is no way to enforce that a resource has an acl.
>   Also important are the partial unique indexes. Limiting the unique
>   indexes to only not null values dramatically saves space as well as
>   reducing write operations on insert.

Comment: B-E-A-utiful Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

To clearly answer your question, you can't keep relational integrity without creating at least another two tables, one to store relational ids between your Model and your Items, and another one to store all data for the Items you want to create, in this case you will end up with just two more tables, but pain in the future will be cured now.